# Excel: Delete row if cell in certain column is blank?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to delete all of the rows that don't contain a value in column C. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 49):

You can do this very quickly if the cells are truly blank using `SpecialCells`

**Manual**

- Select Column C
- Press `F5`, then `Special`
- Check `Blanks`, then `OK` (see this step in the pic at bottom)
- Delete the rows that are now selected (e.g. right click in selection > *Delete cells...* > *Entire row* or via the ribbon (see second screenshot))

**VBA**

```vb
Sub QuickCull()
    On Error Resume Next
    Columns("C").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot showing the Go To Special -> Blanks menu]
[image: Screenshot showing how to use the ribbon to delete entire rows in selection]

Comment: I wish I knew this years ago

Answer (score 13):

Here's an easy manual method

1. Apply an `Auto Filter` to your sheet
2. Filter on column `C` Blank
3. Select all visible rows
4. Delete Rows
5. Remove filter

This process can be automated with VBA if required.  Try running the macro recorder to get a start

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest thing assuming you don't have a bunch of other formulas in the other cells is to just sort everything by Column C and then delete all the rows that have a blank for column C(the sort function will put the blank values for column C at the top of the file).

In summary:

- Click on the folded paper cell above cell marked "1" and to the left of cell 
  marked "A" (to highlight all)
- Click on Data, and then sort
- Sort by Column C, and make smallest values be first
- Just highlight the rows down until you hit the first row with a value for 
  Column C, and delete everything you highlighted

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```vb
Columns("C:C").Select
Set rngRange = Selection.CurrentRegion
lngNumRows = rngRange.Rows.Count
lngFirstRow = rngRange.Row
lngLastRow = lngFirstRow + lngNumRows - 1
lngCompareColumn = ActiveCell.Column
For lngCurrentRow = lngLastRow To lngFirstRow Step -1
If (Cells(lngCurrentRow, lngCompareColumn).Text = "") Then _
Rows(lngCurrentRow).Delete
Next lngCurrentRow
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put this code in Sheet Module (Right Mouse Click Sheet Tab and select "View Code"):

```
Sub Delete_Blank_Rows()


'Deletes the entire row within the selection if the ENTIRE row contains no data.

'We use Long in case they have over 32,767 rows selected.

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Integer

'We turn off calculation and screenupdating to speed up the macro.

 With Application
     .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     .ScreenUpdating = False

     'Reduce the work on the calc and define the range

     LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Select

     'We work backwards because we are deleting rows.

     For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
          If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
              Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
          End If
     Next i

    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This deletes rows where the entire row is blank? -if does, it's similar to @drnewman answer.
Question specifically states: Delete row if cell in certain column is blank.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.