# move data from rows to columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet that contains rows with an empty id value, I want to move this rows to a separate column to make sure every row in the file will have an id value, for example:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
   1     name1
   2     name2
         name3
   3     name4
         name5
   4     name6
```

And I want to convert it to be like the following:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
   1     name1
   2     name2   name3         
   3     name4   name5         
   4     name6
```

first of all, I copied the whole `ColumnB` and paste it in a new column which is `ColumnC`, so for now I have it to be like:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
   1     name1   name1
   2     name2   name2
         name3   name3
   3     name4   name4
         name5   name5
   4     name6   name6
```

now what I have to do is to:

1- delete the rows in `ColumnC` that already have a value at `ColumnA`.

2- after that, shift every row that has a value in `ColumnC` by one row up.

3- after that, delete all the rows with no values at `ColumnA` from the entire sheet.

I know it's kinda a little wide question, but in fact I have a very little experience in Excel, and for sure I tried my best in searching for a solution but got nothing.
I had a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1132924/excel-2016-how-can-i-move-data-from-rows-to-columns) , [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1028287/excel-converting-rows-to-columns), and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/474530/excel-delete-row-if-cell-in-certain-column-is-blank) but didn't reach a solution to my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution without macros:

1. use a formula to fill appropriate values in third column:
   `=IF(AND(A2="",B2<>""),B2,"")`

[image]

2. convert your third column from formula to constants:

   - select the column and press CTRL+C
   - without changing selection go to home - paste - paste special - values
3. delete rows where first column is empty:

   - select first column
   - go to home - find & select - go to special - select blanks and press ok
     this will keep only blank cells selected
   - right click on a selected cell - delete - select "entire row" and press ok